# Two dataframes merge, groupby, aggregate by conctatenating values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that I want to merge using left join, and bring only Codes from second dataframe but to show its values in a single string comma separated.

What is the best way to do this?

[image: Simplified view]

Comment: please provide your data in a reproducible format (text, code), not images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
df1.merge(df2.groupby('DF2_ID2', as_index=False).agg(', '.join), on='DF2_ID'))
```